# InvalidKey in MongoDB and Node.js

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I have a file which has key as IP `"10.11.190.14:cgi6web-1"`:    . When I try to insert the file in mongoDB, I get the following error:

> Error: key 10.11.190.14:cgi6-web-1 must not contain '.'
>       at Error (unknown source).

I dont have permissions to change the file , is there any work around to write the file to mongoDB with IP as key.

My Code is as follows:

```
var MongoClient = require('./lib/mongodb').MongoClient;
var file = require (__dirname + '/functions.json');

MongoClient.connect('mongodb://phx8b03c-fb1d',
    function (err, client) {
        if (err) throw err;

        client.createCollection('lbTopology' , function (err, collection) {
            if (err) throw err;

            collection.insert(file, 'lbTopology' , function (err) {
                if (err) throw err;

                client.close(function (err) {
                    if (err) throw err;

                    console.log('done');
                });
            });
        });
    })
```

Can someone please help me with this?

Comment: Replace '.' with '_' in file keys before trying to insert?

Comment: How do I do that ? Not very good in JS

Comment: Can they be changed from keys to values in the file? Rather than `{ "10.11.190.14:cgi6web-1": ... }`, maybe `{ "key": "10.11.190.14:cgi6web-1", ... }`? It would probably make querying simpler later: `collection.find({ key: '10.11.190.14:cgi6web-1' }, ...)`.

Comment: I don't have permission to edit file, but just  read it and write it to MONGODB

Comment: could you post the json file here? You may redact sensitive fields but  we need the structure to get a sense of how to transform the json file before inserting to MongoDB.

Comment: My jsonFile :"Pools": {
  "10.2.90.83:cgi5-web-1-80": {
   "tags": "dc=PHX odbPool=cgi5-web-1-80",
   "oname": "10.2.90.83:cgi5-web-1-80",
   "pname": "syi-web",
   "oid_suffix": [
   19 ]
  },
  "10.2.91.103:cgi5-web-2-80": {
   "tags": "dc=PHX odbPool=cgi5-web-2-80",
   "oname": "10.2.91.103:cgi5-web-2-80",
   "pname": "syi-web",
   "oid_suffix": [
    13 ]
  }
}

Comment: Also I tried replacing '.' with '_' before in file inserting:                                                           var file = require (__dirname + '/functions-processed.json');
  var resultFile = file.replace(/./g, '_');      but got an error saying :  TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'replace'

Answer (score 3):

You could possibly change `"Pools"` [as it is in the file](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18118603/#comment26529191_18118603) to an `Array`, moving the key so it's a property of each inner `Object`:

```
{
    "Pools": [
        {
            "_key": "10.2.90.83: cgi5-web-1-80",
            "tags": "dc=PHXodbPool=cgi5-web-1-80",
            "oname": "10.2.90.83: cgi5-web-1-80",
            "pname": "syi-web",
            "oid_suffix": [
                19
            ]
        },
        // ...
    ]
}
```

You can use [`Object.keys()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) and [`.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to accomplish this:

```
var file = require (__dirname + '/functions.json');

file.Pools = Object.keys(file.Pools).map(function (key) {
    var pool = file.Pools[key];
    pool._key = key;
    return pool;
});
```

[Edit] `LBs` will be a bit more interesting as each object has a `pnames` that needs the same treatment. Also, since each item under `pnames` is a `Number`, you'll have to create an `Object` to hold it with its key.

```
file.LBs = Object.keys(file.LBs).map(function (key) {
    var lb = file.LBs[key];
    lb._key = key;

    lb.pnames = Object.keys(lb.pnames).map(function (pkey) {
        return { key: pkey, value: lb.pnames[pkey] };
    });

    return lb;
});
```

Comment: Thanks Jonathan. So instead of using            collection.insert(file, 'lbTopology' , function (err) {
                if (err) throw err;                                    I need to use collection.insert(pool, 'lbTopology' , function (err) {
                if (err) throw err; ??

Comment: @user2325703 This should allow you to still `.insert(file, ...)`. It just alters the `Pools` property before that so Mongo will be more accepting of it.

Comment: @JonathanLonowski Wouldn't this incur a bit overhead while saving, indexing etc ?

Comment: @S.D. Well, some, I'm sure. I don't know enough about profiling Mongo to really answer. Though, I wouldn't think this would cause anymore overhead than was attempted with the original object.

Comment: @ Jonathan. Itworked ..Thanks a lot. I have 1 more JSON file. "LBs": {
  "10.11.190.14": {
   "tags": "lbtype=netscaler-shared-primary host=sjclb99-map00.sjc.com",
   "oname": "10.11.190.14",
   "pnames": {
    "10.11.190.14:cgi6-web-1": 1,
    "10.11.190.14:icgi6-web-1": 1  },                                                                    Since pnames also have Key ,value. I tried this function  file.LBs.pnames = Object.keys(file.LBs.pnames).map(function (key) {
    var lbPname = file.LBs.pnames[key];
    lbPname._key = key;
    return lbPname;
});
 but dint work

Comment: @user2325703 You should probably edit the sample JSON data into your question so they aren't scattered throughout comments. But, you won't be able to convert `pnames` collectively since they'll be spread through `LBs`. See my edit.